# Duration of a Contract within a year

Tags: powerbi, measure

Team,

I tried this formula to get my contract amounts returned within a year. It's saying 'argument '2' in SUMX function is required. Am I missing a bracket somewhere?

Z - No Contract Value = if(HASONEVALUE('Z - Contract Calender'[Year]),COUNTROWS('Sales Force_Contract')*MIN('Sales Force_Contract'[Z - Daily Rate]),SUMX(SUMMARIZE(VALUES('Z - Contract Calender'[Year]),'Z - Contract Calender'[Year],"ABCD",COUNTROWS('Sales Force_Contract')*MIN('Sales Force_Contract'[Z - Daily Rate])),))

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to provide the second argument value as shown below-

```
Z - No Contract Value = 
if(
    HASONEVALUE('Z - Contract Calender'[Year]),
    COUNTROWS('Sales Force_Contract') * MIN('Sales Force_Contract'[Z - Daily Rate]),
    SUMX(
        SUMMARIZE(
            VALUES('Z - Contract Calender'[Year]),
            'Z - Contract Calender'[Year],
            "ABCD",COUNTROWS('Sales Force_Contract') * MIN('Sales Force_Contract'[Z - Daily Rate])
        )
        ,
        //You are missing something here after the comma
    )
)
```